# Laravel How to update value to another column in another table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have two tables named 'users' and 'requests'. In requests table, i want to update users emp_status to 'Admin' and at the same time at table 'users' too.

Here is my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $status = "Admin";

    $admin = DB::table('users')
            ->where('emp_no', $id)
            ->update(array('emp_status'=>$status));

    $forms = Requests::find($id);
    $forms->emp_no = $request->get('emp_no');
    $forms->emp_name = $request->get('emp_name');
    $forms->email = $request->get('email');
    $forms->department = $request->get('department');
    $forms->emp_status = $request->get('emp_status', $admin);
    $forms->justification = $request->get('justification');

    $forms->save();

    return redirect('admins.request')->with('Success','Employee has been changed to admin!');
}
```

Requests Model:

```
class Requests extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [     
        'emp_no','emp_name','email','emp_status','department','justification'
    ];

   public function User(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Requests');
   }
}
```

User Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'emp_no', 'emp_name', 'emp_contact','gender','email','password'
];

public function Requests(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Requests');
}
```

When i select the 'Admin' option in the form and click approve, it should update the two tables at the same time according to emp_no. Here is the screenshot.
[The Form Details blade file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY2xS.png)

How should i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the `<select>` in your blade file is defined like this:

```
<select id="status" name="status">
<option value="Admin">Admin</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
</select>
```

Then in your controller you call it with this `$request->status`

But since your updating two tables at the same time, you should enclose the inside of the updating method with a `transaction` scope, so that way if any error happens during the process it would *rollback*:

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($id, $request){


    $admin = DB::table('users')
        ->where('emp_no', $id)
        ->update(array('emp_status'=>$request->status));

    $forms = Requests::find($id);
    $forms->emp_no = $request->get('emp_no');
    $forms->emp_name = $request->get('emp_name');
    $forms->email = $request->get('email');
    $forms->department = $request->get('department');
    $forms->emp_status = $request->get('status');
    $forms->justification = $request->get('justification');

    $forms->save();
});
```

Comment: Hello, when i tried this i get the syntax error of undefined variable:id. And in my blade file, i used this method: 
<div class="form-group">
<label for="emp_status">Employee Status</label>
<select name="emp_status" class="form-control">
 <option value="Normal" <?php if($forms->emp_status=='Normal' echo'selected="selected"'; ?> >Normal</option>

Maybe it got something to with this?

Comment: @WIlliamFWL I edited the header of `DB::transaction` try copying the new header and see if it works.

Comment: I got no errors but it just update the request table and not the users table

Comment: Replace the `->update` in `users` with `->update(['emp_status' =>  $request->get('status')])`

Comment: It's still the same :(